# "Scripting.FileSystemObject" Replacement module in VBA

Tags: file-system, vba

I have found *Scripting.FileSystemObject* to be slow and unstable.  Calling `file_object.Name` repeatedly has caused my code to crash excel on multiple instances.  Therefore I made a module where all of my file System helper functions reside.  I called it `os` after python's `os` module as I tried to emulate it as much as possible.  Admittedly, I have not emulated it enough and much is written from scratch.

While I haven't been able to run extensive comparisons against it and *FileSystemObject*. I have found that it is significantly faster.  It varies from operation to operation but the range is 4-10 times faster.  However, I do suspect that *FileSystemObject* may out-perform `os` in larger data-sets.

There are some few questionable design calls.  Nothing is object oriented. Functional programming is preferred whenever possible.  Almost all variables are strings (file paths) or collections of strings.  The exceptions are the file system operations like `FileCopy`, `Move`, `Rename` etc that return `True` if succeeded or `False` if failed as Error Handling is a horrid mess of `GoTo`s in VB6.  Also they are hard set to never overwrite files; only `Remove` deletes anything.

I am looking for more functions, features and improvements for existing functions.

```
Option Explicit
' Constants
' ------
Public Const EXTSEP As String = "."
Public Const PARDIR As String = ".."
Public Const CURDIR As String = "."
Public Const SEP As String = "\"
Public Const PATHSEP As String = ";"

Private Const ALLPAT As String = "*"
```

### Path Manipulations

These functions would be in `os.path`. They have no interaction with the file system at all and are primarily helper functions.

```
''
' Returns the base name of a path, either the lowest folder or file
' Note! that `suffix` will be removed from the end regardless if its an actual filename
' extension or not.
Function BaseName(ByVal file_path As String, Optional suffix As String) As String

    Dim fsplit As Variant
    fsplit = Split(file_path, sep)

    BaseName = fsplit(UBound(fsplit))

    If suffix <> "" Then
        Dim base_length As Integer
        base_length = Len(BaseName) - Len(suffix)
        BaseName = left$(BaseName, base_length) & _
                   Replace$(BaseName, suffix, "", base_length + 1)
    End If

End Function
''
' Returns the path of the parent folder. This is the opposite of `BaseName`.
Function RootName(ByVal file_path As String) As String

    Dim fsplit As Variant
    fsplit = Split(file_path, sep)
    If UBound(fsplit) = 0 Then
        RootName = ""
    Else
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = LBound(fsplit) To UBound(fsplit) - 1

            RootName = RootName & fsplit(i) & SEP

        Next i
        RootName = left$(RootName, Len(RootName) - 1)
    End If
End Function
Function ParentDir(ByVal file_path As String, _
                   ByVal parent_height As Integer) As String

    ParentDir = file_path
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To parent_height
        ParentDir = RootName(ParentDir)
    Next i
End Function
''
' Returns the file extension of the file.
Function ext(ByVal file_path As String) As String
    Dim base_name As String
    base_name = BaseName(file_path)
    If InStr(base_name, EXTSEP) Then

        Dim fsplit As Variant
        fsplit = Split(base_name, EXTSEP)

        ext = EXTSEP & fsplit(UBound(fsplit))

    End If

End Function
Function ChangeExt(ByVal file_path As String, ByVal new_ext As String) As String

    Dim current_ext As String
    current_ext = ext(file_path)

    ChangeExt = left$(file_path, Len(file_path) - Len(current_ext)) & _
                EXTSEP & Replace$(new_ext, EXTSEP, "", 1, 1)

End Function
Private Function RTrimSep(ByVal file_path As String) As String
    If right$(file_path, 1) = sep Then
        RTrimSep = left$(file_path, Len(file_path) - 1)
    Else
        RTrimSep = file_path
    End If
End Function
''
' safely join two strings to form a path
Function pJoin(ByVal root_path As String, ByVal file_path As String) As String

        pJoin = RTrimSep(root_path) & SEP & file_path

End Function
Function Append(ByVal file_path As String, ByVal to_append As String) As String

    Dim file_ext As String
    file_ext = ext(file_path)

    Append = pJoin(RootName(file_path), _
                   BaseName(file_path, suffix:=file_ext) & _
                   to_append & file_ext)

End Function
Function Prepend(ByVal file_path As String, ByVal to_prepend As String) As String

    Prepend = pJoin(RootName(file_path), to_prepend & BaseName(file_path))

End Function
```

### Introspect File System

The following functions read the file system but make no changes.

```
''
' returns true if the file exists else false.
' You can give a pat as f to see if anything matches the pat
Function Exists(ByVal file_path As String, _
                Optional vbType As Integer = vbDirectory) As Boolean

    If file_path <> "" Then Exists = (Dir$(RTrimSep(file_path), vbType) <> "")

End Function
Function FileExists(ByVal file_path As String)

    FileExists = Exists(file_path, vbNormal)

End Function
''
' vbDirectory option still includes files.
' FML
Function FolderExists(ByVal file_path As String)

    FolderExists = Exists(file_path, vbDirectory) And Not Exists(file_path, vbNormal)

End Function
''
' returns a collection of strings that are paths of subitems in root which
' match pat.
Function SubItems(ByVal root As String, Optional pat As String = ALLPAT, _
                  Optional vbType As Integer = vbDirectory) As Collection

    Set SubItems = New Collection

    Dim sub_item As String
    sub_item = Dir$(pJoin(root, pat), vbType)

    While sub_item <> ""

        SubItems.Add (pJoin(root, sub_item))
        sub_item = Dir$()

    Wend

End Function
Function SubFiles(ByVal root As String, _
                  Optional pat As String = ALLPAT) As Collection

    Set SubFiles = SubItems(root, pat, vbNormal)

End Function
Function SubFolders(ByVal root As String, Optional pat As String = "", _
                    Optional skipDots As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Set SubFolders = SubItems(root, pat, vbDirectory)

    If skipDots And SubFolders.count > 0 Then

        Dim dot As String, dotdot As String
        dot = pJoin(root, CURDIR)
        dotdot = pJoin(root, PARDIR)

        Do While SubFolders.Item(1) = dot Or SubFolders.Item(1) = dotdot

            SubFolders.Remove (1)
            If SubFolders.count = 0 Then Exit Do

        Loop

    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = SubFolders.count To 1 Step -1

        If FileExists(SubFolders.Item(i)) Then
            SubFolders.Remove (i)
        End If

    Next i

End Function
''
' recursive search
Sub sWalk(ByVal root As String, ByRef collec As Collection, _
          Optional pat As String = "*", Optional vbType As Integer = vbNormal)

    Dim file_path As Variant
    For Each file_path In SubItems(root, pat, vbType)
        collec.Add file_path
    Next file_path

    Dim folder_path As Variant
    For Each folder_path In SubFolders(root)
         sWalk folder_path, collec, pat, vbType
    Next folder_path

End Sub
Function fWalk(ByVal root As String, Optional pat As String = "*", _
               Optional vbType As Integer = vbNormal) As Collection

    Set fWalk = New Collection

    sWalk root, fWalk, pat, vbType

End Function
```

### File System Operations

The following functions are the only functions that actually change the file system.  Note that only `Remove` deletes any data.  The rest will return `False` if they would remove or overwrite any data, or if they cannot perform the operation for any other reason.

```
Function Move(ByVal file_path As String, ByVal new_path As String, _
              Optional create_parent As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Move = Exists(file_path) And Not Exists(new_path)

    If Move Then

        If create_parent Then CreateRootPath new_path
        Name file_path As new_path

    End If

End Function
Function Rename(ByVal file_path As String, ByVal new_name As String) As Boolean


    Debug.Assert BaseName(new_name) = new_name

    new_name = pJoin(RootName(file_path), new_name)

    Rename = Exists(file_path) And Not Exists(new_name)

    If Rename Then Name file_path As new_name

End Function
Function Remove(file_path As String) As Boolean

    Remove = FileExists(file_path)

    If Remove Then Kill file_path

End Function
''
' $ mkdir -p
Private Sub CreateRootPath(file_path As String)

    If Not Exists(RootName(file_path)) Then

        MakeDir RootName(file_path), create_parent:=True

    End If

End Sub
Function MakeDir(folder_path As String, _
                Optional create_parent As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    MakeDir = Not Exists(folder_path)

    If MakeDir Then

        If create_parent Then CreateRootPath folder_path
        MkDir folder_path

    End If

End Function
Function CopyFile(file_path As String, dest_path As String, _
                  Optional create_parent As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    CopyFile = Exists(file_path) And Not Exists(dest_path)

    If CopyFile Then

        If create_parent Then CreateRootPath dest_path
        FileCopy file_path, dest_path

    End If

End Function
```

---

#### Error Handling

I implemented the Error Handling as suggested.  I noticed I could remove almost all of my guards because the VB methods would throw errors anyways.  Except for `FileCopy` which would overwrite existing files.

```
Function Move(ByVal src_path As String, ByVal dest_path As String, _
              Optional create_parent As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim check As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If right$(dest_path, 1) = SEP Or FolderExists(dest_path) Then
        ' Move the file to a folder.  Note this cannot be used with the
        ' create_parent option.
        dest_path = pJoin(dest_path, BaseName(src_path))

    End If

    If create_parent Then CreateRootPath dest_path
    Name src_path As dest_path
    check = Exists(dest_path)

CleanExit:
    Move = check
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Err.clear
    Debug.Assert (Not check)
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
Function Rename(ByVal file_path As String, ByVal new_name As String) As Boolean

    Debug.Assert BaseName(new_name) = new_name

    Rename = Move(file_path, pJoin(RootName(file_path), new_name))

End Function
Function Remove(file_path As String) As Boolean

    Dim check As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Kill file_path
    check = (Not FileExists(file_path))

CleanExit:
    Remove = check
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Err.clear
    Debug.Assert (Not check)
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
Function MakeDir(folder_path As String, _
                Optional create_parent As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim check As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If create_parent Then CreateRootPath folder_path
    MkDir folder_path
    check = FolderExists(folder_path)

CleanExit:
    MakeDir = check
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Err.clear
    Debug.Assert (Not check)
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
Function CopyFile(src_path As String, dest_path As String, _
                  Optional create_parent As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim check As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If FileExists(dest_path) Then GoTo CleanExit:

    If create_parent Then CreateRootPath dest_path
    FileCopy src_path, dest_path

    check = FileExists(dest_path)

CleanExit:
    CopyFile = check
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Err.clear
    Debug.Assert (Not check)
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
Private Sub CreateRootPath(path As String)

    Dim parent_folder As String
    parent_folder = RootName(path)

    If Not FolderExists(parent_folder) Then

        MakeDir parent_folder, create_parent:=True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You might be interested in reviewing [this somewhat related code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/52306/23788)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just one quick little comment, about this function... which turns out being applicable to the whole:

> ```
> Function Remove(file_path As String) As Boolean
>
>     Remove = FileExists(file_path)
>
>     If Remove Then Kill file_path
>
> End Function
> ```

---

You're returning `True` if `FileExists(file_path)` returns `True`, not if the `Kill` call succeeded. And what happens if `Kill` blows up, *your method blows up with it*, and your client code is probably simply expecting the call to return `False` if the `Kill` somehow *can't happen right now*, whatever the reason is. What the client wants, is to delete the file.

I'd avoid underscores in identifiers, and keep them for event handler procedures and interface implementations. Also I don't like using the function's *return value* as a *variable* in a function's logic.

Consider this:

```
Function Remove(path As String) As Boolean
Const method As String = "Remove"
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim exists As Boolean
    Dim check As Boolean

    exists = FileExists(path)

    If exists Then 

        Kill path        
        check = Not FileExists(path)

    End If

CleanExit:
    Remove = check
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
'    Err.Raise Err.Number, TypeName(Me) & "." & method, Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Debug.Assert (Not check)
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
```

If I un-comment the `Err.Raise` call, I'll *bubble up* the error to the client code like your code does now - but you can take control of that, and add something meaningful to the error's `Source` property, so the client code can know in which method the error was raised from. In this case though, I think it's best to handle any errors that may be raised in the process, and simply return `True` or `False` - your client code likely is only expecting a `False` if anything failed.

Notice how `exists` does not have the same meaning as `check` and `Remove`:

- `exists` is the condition we need to fulfill *in order to* perform the `Kill` call
- `check` defaults to `False`, and can only be `True` if the file `exists` and the `Kill` call didn't blow up.
- `Remove` is the return value, accessed/assigned *once*.

In case of an error - *any* error, code jumps to `Err.Clear` and then `Resume CleanExit` jumps to `Remove = check` which is `False` at that point, and then `Exit Function`: client code sees nothing but a `False` return value.

In the debugger, the `Debug.Assert` will break whenever `check` is `True`, just prior to returning that value. Use `Debug.Assert` to verify assumptions the code is making - in this case, that `check` is `False`.

Comment: It would be even better to explicitly set check = false after clearing the error.

Comment: Depends how you see it: I find it more explicit to see `check` only assigned once... implicitly.... right. lol, indeed, it would be more explicit :)

Comment: Added `Debug.Assert` as a counterpoint ;)

Comment: Love the `Debug.Assert`, but I'm not sure how client code will react to it. I'll have to research that later.

Comment: `Debug.Assert (not check)` will never be false.  `FileExists` would need to throw and error after returning `True` which AFAIK is impossible.

Comment: @ptwales exactly. Hence it's an *assertion* that documents an *intent* to whoever is maintaining the code, without affecting its execution (outside the debugger that is) - whatever changes are made to the code, they know that the error-handling subroutine *assumes* `check` is `False` when that code runs.

Answer (score 9):

Once you've fixed [the things that could potentially crash your code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52328/41243) and added some proper error handling you should go back and take a look at some style & readability issues.

1. Remove the underscores from your variable names. Style conventions say to use camelCase. `file_path` should be `filePath`, etc.
2. I like that you created constants for the different separators, but give them better names. Unless you're coding in a plain text editor, intellisense will help you and there's no reason to abbreviate.

   ```
   Public Const EXTSEPERATOR As String = "."
   Public Const PARENTDIR As String = ".."
   Public Const CURRENTDIR As String = "."
   Public Const FWDSLASH As String = "\"
   Public Const PATHSEPERATOR As String = ";"
   Private Const WILDCARD As String = "*"
   ```
3. On the topic of better names, what is `fsplit()`? It took me way too long to figure out that it's an array that stores the separate parts of a file path.
4. I recently [had it pointed out to me](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/51882/41243) that it's better to use `Not = vbNullString` than `<> ""` and I'll pass that advice along to you.
5. Functions should have verb-noun type names.

   ```
   Function SubFiles(ByVal root As String, _
                     Optional pat As String = ALLPAT) As Collection

       Set SubFiles = SubItems(root, pat, vbNormal)

   End Function
   ```

   Should be `getSubFiles()` or `returnSubFiles`, but you could keep your naming if...
6. You considered an object oriented approach. Instead of returning a collection of `SubItems` or `SubFiles` from a function, you could store them a a property of a parent class. I haven't thought out how I would refactor your code into classes, but any client code might benefit from it. (Of course, this would still require a *private* `getSubFiles()` routine though.)
7. Think of Mr. Maintainer; add some comments to non obvious logic.

   ```
   Dim base_length As Integer
   base_length = Len(BaseName) - Len(suffix)
   BaseName = left$(BaseName, base_length) & _
              Replace$(BaseName, suffix, "", base_length + 1)
   ```

   Could I spend a few minutes figuring out what exactly you're doing here? Sure, but it'd be a heck of a lot nicer if you wrote one sentence *telling* me what you're doing.

All that said, I still think it's a pretty cool little module of functions. Fun idea.

Answer (score 7):

Just a thing I wanted to get finished as the other answers didn't mention it yet:

#### Spacing:

Be consistent in your usage of *newlines*:

> ```
> Function Rename(ByVal file_path As String, ByVal new_name As String) As Boolean
>
>
>     Debug.Assert BaseName(new_name) = new_name
>
>     new_name = pJoin(RootName(file_path), new_name)
>
>     Rename = Exists(file_path) And Not Exists(new_name)
>
>     If Rename Then Name file_path As new_name
>
> End Function
> ```

compared to:

> ```
> Private Function RTrimSep(ByVal file_path As String) As String
>     If right$(file_path, 1) = sep Then
>         RTrimSep = left$(file_path, Len(file_path) - 1)
>     Else
>         RTrimSep = file_path
>     End If
> End Function
> ```

I would **love** to see a consistent spacing behavior in that code ;)
IMO it does not matter which of the two you choose (though personally I prefer the latter one), but you should definitely stick with *one way to do it.*

It's rather confusing for me to have so much newlines as I use them to separate logically independent actions:

```
Function Rename(ByVal file_path As String, ByVal new_name As String) As Boolean 
    Debug.Assert BaseName(new_name) = new_name

    new_name = pJoin(RootName(file_path), new_name)
    Rename = Exists(file_path) And Not Exists(new_name)

    If Rename Then 
        Name file_path As new_name
End Function
```