# Extending the VBA Extensibility Library

Tags: object-oriented, vba, error-handling, vb6, meta-programming

The Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility library let's us meta-program VBA, but the way it handles (or rather, doesn't handle) getting to the actual subs and functions is clunky at best. I decided to write a few class modules to make it easier.

Considering this can be kind of dangerous to do, I want to know that it's working the way I think it does without unintended side effects. Of course, I'm also interested in other feedback. I'd like to gauge if I've learned anything over the last few days here. I feel like I have the logic and style pretty tight, so I'm particularly interested in hearing thoughts on how I handled the object model.

There are three classes:

1. vbeProcedure - does most of the heavy lifting of getting us the procedures.
2. vbeProcedures - Simple collection class that holds only the vbeProcedure type.
3. vbeCodeModule - Ties the VBIDE.CodeModule object to a vbeProcedures collection (as well as actually creating that collection.)

The project requires references to both the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3** and **Microsoft Access 14.0 Object** libraries.

**vbeCodeModule**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private mCodeModule As CodeModule
Private mVbeProcedures As VbeProcedures

Public Property Get CodeModule() As CodeModule
    Set CodeModule = mCodeModule
End Property

Public Property Let CodeModule(ByRef CodeMod As CodeModule)
    Me.Initialize CodeMod
End Property

Public Property Get VbeProcedures()
    Set VbeProcedures = mVbeProcedures
End Property

Public Sub Initialize(CodeMod As CodeModule)
    Set mCodeModule = CodeMod
    Set mVbeProcedures = getProcedures(mCodeModule)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mVbeProcedures = Nothing
    Set mCodeModule = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function getProcedures(CodeMod As CodeModule) As VbeProcedures
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Returns collection of all vbeProcedures in a CodeModule            '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim procName As String
    Dim lastProcName As String
    Dim procs As New VbeProcedures
    Dim proc As vbeProcedure

    Dim i As Long
    ' Skip past any Option statement
    '   and any module-level variable declations.

    For i = CodeMod.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1 To CodeMod.CountOfLines
        ' get procedure name
        procName = CodeMod.ProcOfLine(i, vbext_pk_Proc)
        If Not procName = lastProcName Then
            ' create new procedure object
            Set proc = New vbeProcedure
            proc.Initialize procName, CodeMod
            ' add it to collection
            procs.Add proc
            ' reset lastProcName
            lastProcName = procName
        End If
    Next i
    Set getProcedures = procs

End Function
```

**vbeProcedures**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private mCollection As Collection

Public Sub Clear()
    killVbeProcs
    Set mCollection = New Collection
End Sub

Public Function Add(ByRef vbeProc As vbeProcedure, Optional ByVal Key As Variant)
    If IsMissing(Key) Then
        mCollection.Add vbeProc
    Else
        mCollection.Add vbeProc, Key
    End If
End Function

Public Function Remove(ByVal Index As Variant)
    mCollection.Remove (Index)
End Function

Public Function Item(ByVal Index As Variant) As vbeProcedure
    Set Item = mCollection(Index)
End Function

Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = mCollection.Count
End Function

Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = mCollection.[_NewEnum]
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mCollection = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    killVbeProcs
    Set mCollection = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub killVbeProcs()
    Dim proc As vbeProcedure
    If Not mCollection Is Nothing Then
        For Each proc In mCollection
            Set proc = Nothing
        Next proc
    End If
End Sub
```

**vbeProcedure**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' error handling values
Private Const BaseErrorNum As Long = 3500

Public Enum vbeProcedureError
    vbeObjectNotIntializedError = vbObjectError + BaseErrorNum
    vbeReadOnlyPropertyError
End Enum

Private Const ObjectNotIntializedMsg = "Object Not Initialized"
Private Const ReadOnlyPropertyMsg = "Property is Read-Only after initialization"

' exposed property variables
Private mParentModule As CodeModule
Private mName As String

' truly private property variables
Private isNameSet As Boolean
Private isParentModSet As Boolean

Public Property Get Name() As String
    If isNameSet Then
        Name = mName
    Else
        RaiseObjectNotIntializedError
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal vNewValue As String)
    If Not isNameSet Then
        mName = vNewValue
        isNameSet = True
    Else
        RaiseReadOnlyPropertyError
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get ParentModule() As CodeModule
    If isParentModSet Then
        Set ParentModule = mParentModule
    Else
        RaiseObjectNotIntializedError
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let ParentModule(ByRef vNewValue As CodeModule)
    If Not isParentModSet Then
        Set mParentModule = vNewValue
        isParentModSet = True
    Else
        RaiseReadOnlyPropertyError
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get startLine() As Long
    If isParentModSet And isNameSet Then
        startLine = Me.ParentModule.ProcStartLine(Me.Name, vbext_pk_Proc)
    Else
        RaiseObjectNotIntializedError
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get EndLine() As Long
    If isParentModSet And isNameSet Then
        EndLine = Me.startLine + Me.CountOfLines
    Else
        RaiseObjectNotIntializedError
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get CountOfLines() As Long
    If isParentModSet And isNameSet Then
        CountOfLines = Me.ParentModule.ProcCountLines(Me.Name, vbext_pk_Proc)
    Else
        RaiseObjectNotIntializedError
    End If
End Property

Public Sub Initialize(Name As String, CodeMod As CodeModule)
    Me.Name = Name
    Me.ParentModule = CodeMod
End Sub

Public Property Get Lines() As String
    If isParentModSet And isNameSet Then
        Lines = Me.ParentModule.Lines(Me.startLine, Me.CountOfLines)
    Else
        RaiseObjectNotIntializedError
    End If
End Property

Private Sub RaiseObjectNotIntializedError()
    Err.Raise vbeProcedureError.vbeObjectNotIntializedError, GetErrorSource, ObjectNotIntializedMsg
End Sub

Private Sub RaiseReadOnlyPropertyError()
    Err.Raise vbeProcedureError.vbeReadOnlyPropertyError, GetErrorSource, ReadOnlyPropertyMsg
End Sub

Private Function GetErrorSource() As String
    GetErrorSource = CurrentProject.Name & "." &TypeName(Me)
End Function
```

And finally, **The example call**:

```
Private Sub exampleCall()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim prj As vbProject
    Set prj = VBE.ActiveVBProject

    Dim CodeMod As New vbeCodeModule
    CodeMod.Initialize prj.VBComponents("OraConfig").CodeModule
    Dim proc As vbeProcedure
    For Each proc In CodeMod.vbeProcedures
        With proc
            Debug.Print "ParentModule: " & .ParentModule.Name
            Debug.Print "Name: " & .Name
            Debug.Print "StarLine: " & .startLine
            Debug.Print "EndLine: " & .EndLine
            Debug.Print "CountOfLines: " & .CountOfLines
            'uncommenting the next line will print the procedure's contents
            'Debug.Print .Lines

            ' throw an error for fun.
            ' Sidenote, how can I expose this to vbeCodeModule, but not client code?
            .Initialize "ensureSQLNet", prj.VBComponents("OraConfig").CodeModule
        End With
    Next proc

NormalExit:
    Set CodeMod = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If Err.number = vbeReadOnlyPropertyError Then
        MsgBox "That vbeProcedure is already initialized.", vbExclamation, "Warning"
        Resume Next
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
        Resume NormalExit:
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only coupling I can see with MSAccess-specific [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) is in your `exampleCall` (why is it `Private` anyway?):

```
Dim prj As vbProject
Set prj = VBE.ActiveVBProject
```

Your code works perfectly fine with Excel [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) if you *take in* a `VBProject` parameter:

```
Public Sub exampleCall(project As VBProject)
```

If this code lives in a class module called `Ext`, I can then do this from the *immediate pane* to run the test code with Excel VBA (requires appropriate macro security settings):

```
set x = new Ext
x.examplecall thisworkbook.VBProject
```

---

The `With` block is an abuse here:

> ```
> Dim proc As vbeProcedure
> For Each proc In CodeMod.vbeProcedures
>     With proc
>         Debug.Print "ParentModule: " & .ParentModule.Name
>         Debug.Print "Name: " & .Name
>         Debug.Print "StarLine: " & .startLine
>         Debug.Print "EndLine: " & .EndLine
>         Debug.Print "CountOfLines: " & .CountOfLines
>         'uncommenting the next line will print the procedure's contents
>         'Debug.Print .Lines
>
>         ' throw an error for fun.
>         ' Sidenote, how can I expose this to vbeCodeModule, but not client code?
>         .Initialize "ensureSQLNet", prj.VBComponents("OraConfig").CodeModule
>     End With
> Next proc
> ```

I don't mean to sound rude or anything, but you're just being lazy, it should read like this:

```
Dim proc As vbeProcedure
For Each proc In CodeMod.vbeProcedures
    Debug.Print "ParentModule: " & proc.ParentModule.Name
    Debug.Print "Name: " & proc.Name
    Debug.Print "StarLine: " & proc.startLine
    Debug.Print "EndLine: " & proc.EndLine
    Debug.Print "CountOfLines: " & proc.CountOfLines
    'uncommenting the next line will print the procedure's contents
    'Debug.Print proc.Lines

    ' throw an error for fun.
    ' Sidenote, how can I expose this to vbeCodeModule, but not client code?
    proc.Initialize "ensureSQLNet", prj.VBComponents("OraConfig").CodeModule

Next proc
```

The reason I'm saying this, is because `With` "holds" the reference for the instance it's working with, which means if there's no other reference to that instance, the `Class_Terminate` procedure gets called and the object is destroyed when the `End With` is reached. You can see this behavior in action in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/52306/23788).

Using `With` just to do less typing (for a 4-letter identifier?) is a misuse of the keyword, in my opinion. And it gets worse when the `With` blocks get nested. *Think of Mr. Maintainer* ;)

---

The class names don't follow naming conventions... but then the language itself lower-cases `vb` when it's used as a prefix to anything, so I'd guess `VbeCodeModule` would just look weird. The ideal name would be simply `CodeModule`, but that forces you to fully-qualify the names:

```
Dim CodeMod As New VBAProject.CodeModule
```

Otherwise `CodeModule` clashes with `VBE.CodeModule`.

The naming convention in VB6/VBA is to use `PascalCase` for everything, but I find it annoying and I tend to make my local variables and parameters `camelCase`. I see you're also doing that:

```
Dim proc As vbeProcedure
```

But inconsistently:

```
Dim CodeMod As New vbeCodeModule
```

Also you're using `camelCase` for `Private` procedures and functions, which is confusing. I wouldn't make that distinction between `Private` and `Public`, and use `PascalCase` for all members, regardless of their accessibility.

---

The `vbeProcedure` class *desperately wants* to be immutable, unfortunately unless you make the setters (*letters?*) `Friend` and compile them into their own DLL (which VBA can't do), there's no way this can work, so you're stuck with settable properties that are meant to be get-only.

You've done well extracting the `RaiseObjectNotInitializedError` and `RaiseReadOnlyPropertyError` code into their own methods, however I'd push the DRY-ing up a step further and create a `Private Sub ValidateIsInitialized()` procedure whose responsibility would be to call `RaiseObjectNotInitializedError` when `ParentModule` is `Nothing` (no need to check for an empty name then), and then this:

> ```
> Public Property Get Lines() As String
>     If isParentModSet And isNameSet Then
>         Lines = Me.ParentModule.Lines(Me.startLine, Me.CountOfLines)
>     Else
>         RaiseObjectNotIntializedError
>     End If
> End Property
> ```

Can turn into that:

```
Public Property Get Lines() As String
    ValidateIsInitialized
    Lines = Me.ParentModule.Lines(Me.StartLine, Me.CountOfLines)
End Property
```

The `Name` property setter (*letter*?) can simply throw an error if the new value is `vbNullString`, as part of regular value validation.

---

I'm surprised this works:

```
Public Property Let ParentModule(ByRef vNewValue As CodeModule)
```

`CodeModule` being an object, the property should have a *setter*:

```
Public Property Set ParentModule(ByRef vNewValue As CodeModule)
```

---

I like that you're using a procedure attribute to enable `For Each` iteration:

```
Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = mCollection.[_NewEnum]
End Function
```

...but then `Item` should be a parameterized, *default* property (with procedure attribute 0):

```
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
```

Also hile I'm on procedure attributes, if you specify a `VB_Description` attribute:

```
Attribute Item.VB_Description = "Gets or sets the element at the specified index."
```

...you can get mini-documentation in the *Object Browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd>):

[image: default property with description attribute, as it appears in the object browser]

<sub>(this screenshot is forged, I used a default property from another project)</sub>

So it would look like this:

```
Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As Variant) As vbeProcedure
Attribute Item.VB_Description = "Gets the procedure at the specified index."
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set Item = mCollection(Index)
End Function
```

Then when can do `Set theFirstProcedure = CodeMod.vbeProcedures(0)` :)

Comment: Great review. I'd upvote twice if I could. Quick question. In `vbeProcedure` the `Property Get EndLine`.. Is it proper to use the keyword `Me` there?

Comment: I hardly ever use `Me` - pretty much like `this` in C#, I tend to only use it when I *need* a reference to the current instance of the type, like in `TypeName(Me)`, or if a method returns `Me`; any other usage is, I find, redundant. But that probably falls under *personal preference*.

Comment: Interesting fact about the `ParentModule` property. If I change it to `Set`, the code breaks. It seems to be a side effect of my use of `Me`. I'll have to think about that on my next version.