# Immutable Linked List in VBA

Tags: linked-list, vba, immutability

I made an immutable list class using the `head-tail` idiom.  If I did this correctly, it implements persistent data structures.  Unfortunately it doesn't scale well as VBA is not tail recursive.  Note: I use a method called `seq.Assign` to handle assigning objects without using `Set`.  I would like to copy the objects and preserve immutability but for now; if you build a List of mutable objects and mutate one of those objects it will mutate the contents of that list and any list built from that list.

Let's get some basics out of the way.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "SList"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True ' Client code cannot use `new` Keyword
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit
```

### Private Members

```
Private TypedName As String
Private pHead As Variant
Private pTail As SList
```

### TypeChecking

SList is also strongly typed using the following methods and boilerplate code

```
''
' TypeCheck:
Friend Sub TypeCheck(ByVal element As Variant, ByVal source As String)

    If TypedName = vbNullString Then TypedName = TypeName(element)
    If (TypeName(element) <> TypedName) Then RaiseTypeError element, source

End Sub
''
' RaiseTypeError:
Private Sub RaiseTypeError(ByVal badItem As Variant, ByVal method As String)
    Err.Raise 13, method, "Element is of type " & TypeName(badItem) & _
                         ", not " & TypedName & "."
End Sub
Private Sub RaiseEmptyError(ByVal method As String)
    Err.Raise 9, TypeName(Me) & "." & method, method & " cannot be called on Empty List!"
End Sub
Private Sub RaiseOutOfRangeError(Byval method As String)
    Err.Raise 9, TypeName(Me) & "." & method, method & " Index is out of range!"
End Sub
```

### Friend Methods (mutability)

These methods violate mutability and should only be used *carefully* in constructor functions.

```
Friend Property Let Head(ByVal x As Variant)
    TypeCheck x, "Head"
    seq.Assign pHead, x
End Property

Friend Property Set refEnd(ByRef that As SList)
    If pTail Is Nothing Then
        Set pTail = that
    ElseIf pTail.IsNil Then
        Set pTail = that
    Else
        Set pTail.refEnd = that
    End If
End Property
```

Note `refEnd` goes to the *entire end* of the list.

### Iteration

The collection must be [persistent in order to iterate over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721017/unable-to-create-new-enum-in-vba/26721972?noredirect=1#comment42034327_26721972).  I chose to keep it static to confine it to this function but that is up for debate.

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4

    Static tempCollection As Collection
    If tempCollection Is Nothing Then Set tempCollection = ToCollection
    Set NewEnum = tempCollection.[_NewEnum]

End Property
```

### Constructors

Client Code will need to use these to create a new `SList` object

#### Basic

```
Public Function Nil() As SList
    Set Nil = New SList
End Function
Public Function Node(ByVal elem As Variant) As SList
    Set Node = Cons(elem, Nil)
End Function
Public Function Cons(ByVal hd As Variant, ByRef tl As SList) As SList
    If Not tl.IsNil Then tl.TypeCheck hd, "Cons"
    Dim made As New SList
    made.Head = hd
    Set made.refEnd = tl
    Set Cons = made
End Function
```

#### Convenience

```
Public Function Create(ParamArray args() As Variant) As SList
    Set Create = Copy(args)
End Function
Public Function Copy(ByVal sequence As Variant) As SList

    Dim result As SList
    Set result = Nil

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In sequence
        If result.IsNil Then
            Set result = Node(element)
        Else
            Set result.refEnd = Node(element)
        End If
    Next

    Set Copy = result

End Function
```

Copy is essential because I use it to copy existing instances as shown in the following `Append` and `Concat`.

#### Builders

I am unsure if my usage of `Copy` and `refEnd` as shortcuts is acceptable.

```
Public Function Prepend(ByVal elem As Variant) As SList

    TypeCheck elem, "Prepend"
    Set Prepend = Cons(elem, Me)

End Function
Public Function Append(ByVal elem As Variant) As SList

    TypeCheck elem, "Append"

    Set Append = Copy(Me)
    Set Append.refEnd = Node(elem)

End Function
Public Function Concat(ByVal that As SList) As SList

    TypeCheck that.Head, "Concat"

    Set Concat = Copy(that)
    Set Concat.refEnd = Me

End Function
```

### Properties

#### Primitive

```
Public Property Get IsNil() As Boolean
    IsNil = IsEmpty(pHead)
End Property
Public Property Get Head() As Variant
    If IsNil Then
        RaiseEmptyError "Head"
    Else
        seq.Assign Head, pHead
    End If
End Property
Public Property Get Tail() As SList
    If IsNil Then
        RaiseEmptyError "Tail"
    Else
        Set Tail = pTail
    End If
End Property
```

#### Non Primitive

```
Public Property Get Last() As Variant
    If IsNil Then
        RaiseEmptyError "Last"
    ElseIf pTail.IsNil Then
        seq.Assign Last, pHead
    Else
        seq.Assign Last, pTail.Last
    End If
End Property
Public Property Get Init() As SList
    If IsNil Then
        RaiseEmptyError "Init"
    ElseIf pTail.IsNil Then
        Set Init = Nil
    Else
        Set Init = pTail.Init.Prepend(pHead)
    End If
End Property
Public Property Get Length() As Long
    If IsNil Then
        Length = 0
    Else
        Length = 1 + pTail.Length
    End If
End Property
Public Property Get Max() As Variant
    If IsNil Then
        Set Max = Nothing
    ElseIf pTail.IsNil Then
        seq.Assign Max, pHead
    Else
        Dim other As Variant
        seq.Assign other, pTail.Max
        seq.Assign Max, IIf(pHead > other, pHead, other)
    End If
End Property
Public Property Get Min() As Variant
    If IsNil Then
        Set Min = Nothing
    ElseIf pTail.IsNil Then
        seq.Assign Min, pHead
    Else
        Dim other As Variant
        seq.Assign other, pTail.Min
        seq.Assign Min, IIf(pHead < other, pHead, other)
    End If
End Property
Public Property Get Reverse() As SList
    If pTail.IsNil Then
        Set Reverse = Me
    Else
        Set Reverse = Node(pHead).Concat(pTail.Reverse)
    End If
End Property
Public Property Get ToArray() As Variant()

    Dim size As Long
    size = Length

    Dim a() As Variant
    ReDim a(size - 1) As Variant
    BuildArray a, 0
    ToArray = a

End Sub
    Friend Sub BuildArray(ByRef a() As Variant, ByVal index As Long)

        If Not IsNil Then
            a(index) = pHead
            pTail.BuildArray a, index + 1
        End If

    End Sub
Public Property Get ToCollection() As Collection

    Dim result As New Collection

    Dim elem As Variant
    For Each elem In ToArray
        result.Add elem
    Next elem

    Set ToCollection = result

End Property
```

### Functions

```
Public Property Get Item(ByVal n As Long) As Variant
    If n = 0 Then
        seq.Assign Item, pHead
    ElseIf pTail.IsNil Then
        RaiseOutOfRangeError("Item")
    Else
        seq.Assign Item, pTail.Item(n - 1)
    End If
End Property
Public Function Take(ByVal n As Long) As SList
    If IsNil Or n <= 0 Then
        Set Take = Nil
    Else
        Set Take = pTail.Take(n - 1).Prepend(pHead)
    End If
End Function
Public Function TakeLeft(ByVal n As Long) As SList
    Set TakeLeft = Drop(Length - n)
End Function
Public Function Drop(ByVal n As Long) As SList
    If n <= 0 Or IsNil Then
        Set Drop = Me
    Else
        Set Drop = pTail.Drop(n - 1)
    End If
End Function
Public Function DropRight(ByVal n As Long) As SList
    Set DropRight = Take(Length - n)
End Function
Public Function DropAt(ByVal n As Long) As SList
    Set DropAt = Drop(n).Concat(Take(n - 1))
End Function
Public Function Contains(ByVal elem As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsNil Then
        Contains = False
    ElseIf elem = pHead Then
        Contains = True
    Else
        Contains = pTail.Contains(elem)
    End If
End Function
Public Function IndexOf(ByVal elem As Variant) As Long
    If pHead = elem Then
        IndexOf = 0
    ElseIf pTail.IsNil Then
        IndexOf = -1
    Else
        Dim index As Long
        index = pTail.IndexOf(elem)
        IndexOf = IIf(index = -1, -1, 1 + index)
    End If
End Function
Public Function LastIndexOf(ByVal elem As Variant) As Long
    LastIndexOf = (Length - 1) - Reverse.IndexOf(elem)
End Function
```

Comment: *These methods violate mutability* - only from within the *same VBAProject*; put this class in an Excel add-in (say, VBToolBox.xlam), and the client code that references it will not be able to call the `Friend` members ;)

Comment: Nicely laid out question ++

Comment: @Mat'sMug that was the idea of making them `Friend`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like that you prefer to use VBA's built in runtime errors, ***but***...

> ```
> Private Sub RaiseEmptyError(ByVal method As String)
>     Err.Raise 9, TypeName(Me) & "." & method, method & " cannot be called on Empty List!"
> End Sub
> Private Sub RaiseOutOfRangeError(Byval method As String)
>     Err.Raise 9, TypeName(Me) & "." & method, method & " Index is out of range!"
> End Sub
> ```

You're raising two different errors with the same error number. As someone using this list, I would probably want to handle those two errors differently, but I would need two different error numbers to do so. I encourage you to define a custom error for the list being empty. The out of range error is fine as it is.

---

The code is neat and clean as far as I can tell. Variables and Methods/Properties have meaningful and clear names mostly. You overshorted some of them and I'm a little confused by what the `Nil` Function is, but I suspect someone familiar with Python wouldn't be. (Okay, I'm not really, but I had to read the code to understand that it returns an empty list).

This could be cleared up with some documentation I suspect. A few comments explaining what each procedure does would go a long way. Perhaps even some [Item.VB_Description attributes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52539/41243) so they show up in intellisense too? That's always nice to have when you're working with an unfamiliar class or library. Of course, don't get carried away. You don't need to tell us what `Contains` does, but it would be nice to understand what `Public Function Cons` is. (Again, I know it's a constructor, but you could never tell that from it's name alone.)

Comment: Please don't consider it a full review. I don't understand linked lists or immutability all that well.

Comment: It's not a Python List which is really a mutable collection. This is supposed to be the generic [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)), common in functional programming languages.

Comment: Sorry. Bad assumption on my part. I know that a lot of your code is meant to mimic Python classes. Oops.

Comment: ++ the documentation and sample use case would be really helpful I think.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's just a comment but generally

```
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True ' Client code cannot use `new` Keyword
```

It doesn't mean that the client code cannot use the new keyword. Changing the attribute to `true` means that this class can also act like a regular standard coding module. Which makes it an imitation of a [static class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59215/28366). The client code can still use the `new` keyword just fine:

```
Dim s As SList
Set s = New SList
' or
Dim sNew As New SList
```

Due to the fact that you actually **can** use the `new` keyword your `Nil` function becomes obsolete. For example in your `Copy` function you have this:

```
Dim result As SList
Set result = Nil
```

Which seems to be nothing else but a wrapper for `Set result = new SList`.

Also, your `ToArray()` throws a `Subscript out of Range` runtime error if `SList` is empty. You may want to handle that by checking either `size` variable or `Length` property is at least `> 0`. Your `ToCollection` would also be affected (would fail) since it uses `ToArray` call in the `for each loop`.

Trying to call a `s.Item(0)` throws a variable not declared error for the `seq` variable. Where is that dimensioned and initialized in your code?

Comment: I think the intent is to keep this in a "library" project, so it needs a factory method of some sort. Setting PredeclaredId=True allows for `Nil` to act as a proxy of sorts.

Comment: @RubberDuck maybe you're right. I based my review off *`I made an immutable list class`*.

Comment: `seq.Assign` is an external method to handle assigning an object or a datatype to a variant as explained in the first paragraph.  `if isObject(y) Then set x=y else x=y endif`