# Glob-Like Search in VBA

Tags: file-system, vba

The `Dir()` function in VB and VBA can accept wildcard characters (* and ?) but only in the basename of the path.

```
Dir("path\*.txt")
```

is a valid request but.

```
Dir("path\*\*.txt")
```

will return *Error 52 "Bad File Name or Number"*, because  `*` is an invalid folder or file name.  I created the ability to use wildcards in the folder names using my
[`os`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52301/scripting-filesystemobject-replacement-module-in-vba) 
module and my 
[`List`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62963/vba-python-like-list-class?lq=1)
 class.

#### Example Call

It's not a true glob search as you can't search like "*.{cpp,hpp}", but this is far better than nothing.  Example:

```
Debug.Print Glob("C:\users\ptwales", "????-herp\*\*.txt").ToString
' ["C:\users\ptwales\derp-herp\flerp\merp.txt", ...]
```

Client code must specify a starting directory.  Current working directory is not implied.

#### Implementation

Note that `os.SubItems` and `os.SubFolders` each now return a `List`.

```
Public Function Glob(ByVal root As String, ByVal pattern As String) As List

    Dim pat_list As New List
    pat_list.Extend Split(pattern, os.SEP)

    Set Glob = GlobRecurse(root, pat_list, 1)

End Function
Private Function GlobRecurse(ByVal root As String, ByVal pat_list As List, ByVal index As Integer) As List

    If index = pat_list.Count Then
        Set GlobRecurse = os.SubItems(root, pat_list(index))
    Else

        Set GlobRecurse = New List

        Dim folder As Variant
        For Each folder In os.SubFolders(root, pat_list(index))
            GlobRecurse.Extend GlobRecurse(folder, pat_list, index + 1)
        Next folder

    End If

End Function
```

It's a bit awkward, particularly that `GlobRecurse` checks the `pat_list.Count` each iteration.  It feels too much like scheme and I should be using a for loop instead.

Comment: Something's not quite right. I don't like that you have a recursive and nonrecursive version of Glob... Yet I do because it hides some complexity that doesn't need to be seen publicly. Hmmm... I'll be back. Need to think on this one.

Comment: Can I assume an example call looks like this, `Glob("C:\path\to\file\*\*.txt")` ?

Comment: I figured out why it looks weird to me. In any *sensible* language, the private sub would actually be an private overloaded version. It's fine. It's just vba being stupid again. (I mean, you could use an optional argument with a default value of 1, but I don't recommend it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Naming, naming, naming.

I've never heard of a "glob search", but I like the idea of implementing it in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). One thing I know, is that I don't expect [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to read like [python](/questions/tagged/python), so `os.SEP` would be clearer as `os.PathSeparator`, or even better, as `path.Separator`. Now I *do* have a tendency to go by [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) naming standards, but really, anything other than a YELLCASE `SEP` would be cleaner and clearer.

Even the [python](/questions/tagged/python) community seems to agree that using `os.path.sep` over `os.sep` makes for clearer code - [*I'd use `os.path.sep` to make it very clear that it's the path separator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900592/1188513) and [*I recommend you use `os.path.sep` for clarity, since it's a path separator, not an OS separator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900583/1188513). So I'd go with `path.Separator`, or `path.Sep` to maintain *Pythonish* naming.

> Looking at your linked question, I see [@RubberDuck already recommended using better names for your constants](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52349/23788); sorry to reiterate the same advice here.

**Underscores**

I know [python](/questions/tagged/python) loves `snake_case`, but in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) that kind of casing is potentially confusing (for class methods, more specifically) - I'd recommend sticking to language's `PascalCase` naming convention, and using a consistent `camelCase` for locals and parameters, for readability's sake (the actual VB/VBA conventions would go `PascalCase` all the way, but I find that maddening). I find `pat_list` would really benefit from simply being called `patterns`, or more accurately, `patternParts` - the `_list` suffix feels Hungarian, and seems to reflect the type, which could just as well be a regular `Collection` - I like that you're using your own `List` type though.

---

#### Parameters

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) I've found actually calls its sole parameter `pathname`:

> glob.**glob**(*pathname*)
>
> *Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be either absolute (like `/usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile`) or relative (like `../../Tools/*/*.gif`), and can contain shell-style wildcards.*

<s>You haven't shown us how the client code might use this function, and it's.. pretty hard to guess just by looking at this post, without diving into the `os` implementation - I'd have to jump to the definition of `os.SubItems` to figure out why I need to pass a `root` parameter on top of a `pattern`.</s>

Looking at your added example call, I think it could be worth combining the two parameters into a single `pathName` parameter, making the function callable like this:

```
?Glob("C:\users\ptwales\????-herp\*\*.txt").ToString
```

The difficulty would be to parse the string and differenciate the `root` from the `pattern` - splitting on path separator and using anything to the left of a part that contains any wildcard as the `root`, and everything else as the `pattern`, would certainly be possible, and would make it a better API IMO; the `root` and `pattern` parts are really two parts of the same string, that you've split in two *because it's more convenient to do so since the implementation calls `os.SubItems` which wants a `root` parameter* - in other words, splitting that string in two is really only leaking implementation details into the API.

---

#### Function as a local variable

I don't like this:

```
Set GlobRecurse = New List
...
GlobRecurse.Extend GlobRecurse(folder, pat_list, index + 1)
```

While this certainly works, it is rather ugly. Not because of multiple *assignments* (roughly requivalent to multiple [non-returning] `return` statements), but because the function's name is being used a local `List` variable, happily being appended to.

I would much rather see this:

```
Private Function GlobRecurse(ByVal root As String, ByVal pat_list As List, ByVal index As Integer) As List

    Dim result As List

    If index = pat_list.Count Then
        Set result = os.SubItems(root, pat_list(index))
    Else

        Set result = New List

        Dim folder As Variant
        For Each folder In os.SubFolders(root, pat_list(index))
            result.Extend GlobRecurse(folder, pat_list, index + 1)
        Next folder

    End If

    Set GlobRecurse = result

End Function
```

**Especially** with the recursive nature of the function, you'll want to avoid repeating the function's name for no reason. My rule of thumb, is to **never** *read* from the function identifier, only to *assign* it.